# Startup applications: open programs in background mode

Tags: release-loki

I've configured Mail and Steam to open at elementary startup, the only problem is that they open as regular apps(popup window), I would like to configure they to open in "background mode", so no popup should open at startp.
It's possible to do that ?

[image: startup applications]

Comment: I found this [little tutorial](https://www.linuxmadesimple.info/2019/12/how-to-add-app-indicators-icons-in.html), and I am using it for skype and slack. It works fin on Elementary Hera 5.1. Hopefully, you can find it useful for steam also. I am not going to paste the code, let's give the author of the real answer some credit. :) Also, I hope it's not too late or u maybe already found the same thing. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you intend, but if you want Mail to run in the background without opening the window, just set Preferences > Always watch for new mail. And this way you can remove Mail from startup applications.

Comment: Yes, it works for Mail, I will keep looking for a solution for steam. Thanks.